# Controller action naming consistency in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I'm confused about the action naming consistency in C# ASP.NET-MVC, let's say I have a simple application with following layer :

`Controller` -> `Service layer` -> `Data Access layer`

Data Access Layer contains a 1:1 class with my database table. Let's say I have 5 tables which is `User`, `UserAddresses`, `Order`, `OrderDetails`, `Product`

I want to group these into 2 groups so :

`CustomerController` contains anything related to `User` and `UserAddresses`
`TransactionController` contains anything related to `Order`, `OrderDetails`, and `Product`

My question is usually Action naming method in controller is something like

```
Index  
Create  
Edit  
Delete  
etc
```

So in my case, how do I keep these naming pattern while I need a separate `Create`, `Edit`, and `Delete` page for `User` and `UserAddreses`.

Any help will be appreciated

Apologize for bad english

Comment: How about `EditUser` and `EditUserAddresses`?

Answer (score 2):

Create two areas

first Area - Customer
 - ControllerUser (Index ,Create ,Edit ,Delete )
 - ControllerUserAddreses (Index ,Create ,Edit ,Delete )

Second Area - Transaction
 -ControllerOrder (Index ,Create ,Edit ,Delete )
 -ControllerOrderDetails (Index ,Create ,Edit ,Delete )
 -ControllerProduct (Index ,Create ,Edit ,Delete )

This design may help you if you want to have index,create, edit ,delete etc

Answer (score 1):

You're following the pattern correctly by having the two different controllers of `CustomerController` and `TransactionController`.

Each controller has it's own CRUD actions and views, so you don't need to worry about naming them any differently.

So you'll typically end up with something like this:

```
CustomerController:
            Create(UserModel theUser)
            Edit(int id, UserModel theUser)
            Delete(int id)


TransactionController:
            Create(OrderModel theOrder)
            Edit(int id, OrderModel theOrder)
            Delete(int id)
```

OrderDetails can be a property of Order, so you don't necessarily need to have an action method for each entity if they're related in this way. The same applies to your user:

```
class UserModel
{
     public List<UserAddress> UserAddresses {get; set; }
}
```